# Problems with non-explainable "Enter Parameter Value" Access

Tags: ms-access

once in a while, I get an absolutely non-explicable "enter parameter value" error in my queries. Sometimes it disappears after closing and opening access or the query a few times.

Example: Query "A" runs totally fine. When I copy+paste query "A" and run it again, the Enter Parameter Value Access error appears.

Has anyone had the same problem before and knows how to solve it?

Another example: Query "B" is exactly the same as query "A" except Query "A" has an additional table in the union statement. So I can't see any reason that Query "A" should not make any problems when Query "B" makes problems, as it is just the result of query "B" + even more necessary information.

What is going on here? The most weird about this is that the enter parameter value error asks for a field completely unrelated to the UNION I am about to open, the table.value in question is not related to my UNION!

The figure  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r5EX.png) shows the original and copy of the same query. I ran the copy and got the shown error message. The SQL-Code is, since its copy+paste, identical.

It is:

> SELECT DS, Produktivvorgang, Nachfolger AS [Logistikvorgang] FROM
>   MML_Nachfolger_Alle UNION ALL  SELECT DS, Produktivvorgang, Vorgaenger
>   AS [Logistikvorgang] FROM MML_Vorgänger_Alle UNION ALL  SELECT DS,
>   Produktivvorgang, Logistikvorgang FROM 
>   Zusatz_Produktivvorgaenge_Vorgaenger;

Comment: A snapshot of the requested parameter prompt, the table design headers and a snippet of the sql code would go a long way here. Its very possible that a slight typo somewhere is causing this problem or forms that should be open were closed etc.

Comment: So it is possible that if I copy+paste a query, the copy behaves different than the original? It is the exact same SQL code. No difference!

Comment: So it is possible that if I copy+paste a query, the copy behaves different than the original? It is the exact same SQL code! Is that really possible? I highly doubt any screenshot will help, since I dont use any forms. But anyways, I will try to add two screenshots of the two queries, one of them asks for a parameter.

Comment: If the errors are so sporadic, try the steps for Access database corruption, e.g. Compact&Repair, Import all objects into a new database.

Comment: Well, sporadic is the wrong description. Just now I had an illogical error again. After simply deleting the columns (fields), which triggered the parameter error (and it still promted me for the old name of the query, "query 21", instead of the name I gave it, also a typical issue...) and then saving and then adding the fields again, it now works. I tried repairing a dozen times and it doesn't help: how do I import (export?) all objects into a new database? EDIT: OK, you ment import, I got it! thx, will update if it helped...

Comment: no, after importing everything into new database i still get the same error for one of my identical duplicates...